# apache ignite - jdbc driver for sql query from cache gives GridClientConnectionResetException when run independently

Tags: ignite

apache ignite 1.7
i have loaded data in cache and ready to query from it.
when run independently using jdbc driver, it gives a 
**"GridClientConnectionResetException: Failed to perform request"**
When i run the same along with the "pre-load cache" code, it runs ok.

### Not sure what am i doing wrong here.

Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver");
Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:ignite://:/);
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet   rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select id,name from ...");

Also, if i use the jdbc:ignite:cfg://, it gives spring context resource is not injected error.
Its the same config used to preload data.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the server node log. Most likely there is an exception that is causing the connection to be closed.

Comment: ok, i checked there and nothing found . thanks for reply though. Any other ideas.

Comment: What is the full trace of the exception then?

Comment: Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientConnectionResetException: Failed to perform request (connection failed): /192.168.13.23:11211
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientConnection.getCloseReasonAsException(GridClientConnection.java:491)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientNioTcpConnection.close(GridClientNioTcpConnection.java:339)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientNioTcpConnection.close(GridClientNioTcpConnection.java:299)

Comment: at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.impl.connection.GridClientConnectionManagerAdapter$NioListener.onDisconnected(GridClientConnectionManagerAdapter.java:624)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onSessionClosed(GridNioFilterChain.java:249)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedSessionClosed(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:93)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onSessionClosed(GridNioCodecFilter.java:70)

Comment: at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedSessionClosed(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:93)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onSessionClosed(GridNioServer.java:2296)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onSessionClosed(GridNioFilterChain.java:147)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.close(GridNioServer.java:1852)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$ByteBufferNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:746)

Comment: at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:1583)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:1516)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1289)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)